# Google GCM Is updated ? old code is not working

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

hello to all   i want to use google gcm for my app .. but now is not working ..

open this url shows warning me warning ..

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/demo.html

The information in this document has been superseded by GCM Server and GCM Client. Please use the GoogleCloudMessaging API instead of the GCM client helper library. The GCM server helper library is still valid.

m confused littel bit .... can any one provide me an latest sample code please

thank you

Comment: it's mentioned in the message click on the `GoogleCloudMessaging` and read

Comment: https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this link to set up your gcm id:
https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html

Comment: If you want to  know how to implement gcm , i can explain it step by step